# How to specify profile based installation in Inno setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I am a newbie to Inno Setup. I am trying to get profile based selection wizard in Inno setup. For example, during installation i want setup to prompt Whether the installation is for Current user or for everyone. 
something like below :

[image: Profile Specific Installation]
Can someone let me know, is there built in wizard is available for this or i will have to go for Custom Wizard?

Thanks

Regards,
Praveen

Answer (score 0):

Your question is rather broad.

Anyway, you can

- use [`[Types]` section](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=typessection) to create per-user and per-machine installation types.
- or use [`[Tasks]` section](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=typessection) to create per-user or per-machine subtasks for specific tasks (such as desktop shortcut creation, like the example in the section documentation shows)

Comment: The screenshot does not make your application more clear.  What is exactly the difference you want to have between "only for me" and "everybody"?

Comment: If it is for "CurrentUser" i will place all the set up files and data files inside appdata of the current user and if it is for "EveryOne" i will put inside program files and program data respectively . I used IntializeWizard method and created new page of my own specifying required fields. It solved my problem. My question was is der any built in wizard for these kind of screen. It seems none.

Comment: Than your question is duplicate, see my comment to the question. Consider accepting the duplicate.